# generate permutations for large data set using dask and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have the following table structure as a pandas data frame (`df`):

```
Key Value
1   A
1   B
1   C
1   D
1   E
1   F
2   A
2   G
2   C
2   F
2   B
3   X
3   Y
3   Z
```

Out of this table, I'm generating the combination of all values for each key using the following command:

```
import itertools
df_new = df.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.permutations(x['Value'],2))))
```

This is working fine and I'm getting the correct results. However, when the size of the data grows (around 20 million rows in `df`), this function takes forever.

That is why I tried using `dask`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
df_new = ddf.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.permutations(x['Value'],2))))
```

This however takes forever to run as well.

Do you have any recommendations, on how can I make this process even more faster? (The option of than chunking and processing the data for each key alone and save everything in a large dataframe at the end is also available, but maybe you guys have a better one?)

Thank you.

Comment: A short / easy input-output example would help.

Comment: Are you considering what the final size of your data set will end up being with all the permutations? With 20MM input rows, will you be able to fit the output in memory, even?